# What is the fastest way to sum two strings made up of only numbers but without converting each to an int beforehand?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance, digits

If I am given two strings made up of only numbers 0-9, what is the fastest way to sum the two? Doing something like  `str(int(num1) + int(num2))` is not allowed and fails.

It mentions in a failed test that the max for an int() is 4300 characters:

```
ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300) for integer string conversion: value has 2102288 digits; use sys.set_int_max_str_digits() to increase the limit
```

Each of the two strings of numbers can be 1,000,000+ characters/numbers long, be empty strings, have mismatched lengths, and/or have leading zeros.

The only way that I can think of is to add each top/bottom digit one at a time from right-to-left and carry the 1 over when necessary.

My version passes all of the tests but fails on long numbers.

```
def sum_strings(x, y):
    if not x:
        x = '0'
    if not y:
        y = '0'
    x_len = len(x)
    y_len = len(y)

    if x_len > y_len:
        y = y.rjust(x_len, '0')
    elif y_len > x_len:
        x = x.rjust(y_len, '0')

    carry = 0
    total = ''
    for index in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):
        new_sum = int(x[index]) + int(y[index]) + carry
        if new_sum > 9:
            new_sum -= 10
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0
        total = f'{new_sum}{total}'

    answer = f'{carry}{total}' if carry else total
    return answer if len(answer) > 1 else answer.lstrip('0')
```

Times out:

[image: test output]

Here are the example "easy" test cases.

```
@test.describe('Basic tests')
def test_examples():

    @test.it('Example tests')
    def basic_tests():
        test.assert_equals(sum_strings("1", "1"), "2")
        test.assert_equals(sum_strings("123", "456"), "579")
```

Is there any way to do it faster?

EDIT: Here is the updated/working version although now that I can see other submissions I think there are cleaner ways to do it than this:

```
def sum_strings(x, y):
    if not x:
        x = '0'
    if not y:
        y = '0'
    x_len = len(x)
    y_len = len(y)

    if x_len > y_len:
        y = y.rjust(x_len, '0')
    elif y_len > x_len:
        x = x.rjust(y_len, '0')

    carry = 0
    total = []
    for index in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):
        new_sum = int(x[index]) + int(y[index]) + carry
        if new_sum > 9:
            new_sum -= 10
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0
        total.append(str(new_sum))

    if carry:
        total.append(str(carry))
    total_str = ''.join(reversed(total))
    return total_str[1:] if len(total_str) > 1 and total_str[0] == '0' else total_str
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I have seen this question already (though I don't remember the user ID). Since you are a new user, I feel I should warn you that deleting your downvoted questions can get you autobanned by the SO algorithm. If it is you, you should edit the downvoted and closed questions to improve them instead. Please read [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/).

Comment: Yes, the previous question was closed before I could finish editing it. I have reposted with a clearer title as I had definitely messed up the previous title. I have also added more information about the test cases.

Comment: Improved questions can be reopened. Deleted questions are frozen in time, waiting for SO to figure out you are more trouble than you're worth and permabanning you (or close to it) from asking any more questions. (Won't happen from this one instance, I don't think, but better to warn you early.)

Comment: To concatenate chars to string, use the "+" rather than the "f'...'" operator.

Comment: @Amadan okay good to know for the future..

Comment: Strings are immutable in python, you are copying "total" all the time (this makes it O(n^2)), you need something like a string builder to build the result. Sorry I don't know enough python.

Comment: Wow, didn't know `int` had a length limit.  I wonder why that is?

Comment: No need to do it one digit at a time, you could do 4299 digits at a time.

Comment: @mark: there's no limit on the size of an int. There's a limit on the length of a decimal conversion between string and int. It was imposed to avoid DOS attacks against servers. The error message tels you how to change the limit, as do the Python docs.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation

Comment: @rici yes sorry, I should have made it clear I was talking about the `int()` function and not the `int` type.  I've made million-digit integers in the past for testing.

Comment: @mark: you still can. You just need to use hexadecimal (or octal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of digits in the order you generate them, then create the final string using `''.join(reversed(digits))`.

Comment: okay using a list sounds like a good idea... will try tonight and mark this answer if I get it using a list

Comment: yep this did the trick... It shows the answers that others have submitted now that I have passed the problem, and many are much better than my solution... but it did pass everything at least.